# upgrade asp.net webpart to visual webpart

Tags: web-part

I have a old asp.net webpart in our application and we want it to upgrade it to visual webpart. Can we achieve this? if yes, how we can do. Please let me know any article/blog or steps to perform the same.

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible, you need to create sharepoint project and build your webparts there before that you must ensure that you have installed all required hardware and software for sharepoint.

For creating visual webpart :

http://sptechbytes.blogspot.in/2013/02/sharepoint-2010-creating-visual-webpart.html